# How can I find the maximum texture size for different phones?

Tags: android, opengl-es, textures, renderer

I'm trying to find out the maximum texture size for the original Motorola Droid. I believe the G1 has a maximum texture size of 512, but it would be nice if there was a more official way I could find out so I can build a proper tile system.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can request the max texture size using glGetIntegerv:

```
int[] maxTextureSize = new int[1];
gl.glGetIntegerv(GL10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, maxTextureSize, 0);
Log.i("glinfo", "Max texture size = " + maxTextureSize[0]);
```

Comment: What is gl?  GLES10?  I tried to run it in onResume of my activity and it returns 0...

Comment: You should make reference to Android's OpenGL ES implementation (`android.opengl.GLES10`); replace the second line with: `GLES10.glGetIntegerv(GLES10.GL_MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE, glInt, 0);`

Comment: That's a dynamically changed value?

Comment: Note that the method returns 0 if there exists no OpenGL context. Adding android:hardwareAccelerated="true" to the application tag in the manifest may help, but I've noticed that this is no guarantee. Here[1] is an extensive answer that creates an OpenGL context before calling this method.

[1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985858/gles10-glgetintegerv-returns-0-in-lollipop-only

Comment: Always returns 0 for me as well.

Answer (score 8):

Also check out http://www.glbenchmark.com/ - it has an extensive database of OpenGL environment and performance details for mobile devices