# Problems when put large image in screen (Andengine)

Tags: android, andengine

I am using andengine to develop a game . The game is running in LANDSCAPE and emulator resolution is 320*480. when I place the background  image as size (320*480) . The images is cleared. But when i place large image (1440*400). The images become  faded images. The game play is to move the background image from left to right. The images width automatically increases and makes fade . How do I fix that problem . I used FillResolutionPolicy

```
public Engine onLoadEngine() {
            this.mCamera = new Camera(0, 0, CAMERA_WIDTH, CAMERA_HEIGHT);
            return new Engine(new EngineOptions(true, ScreenOrientation.LANDSCAPE, new  FillResolutionPolicy(), this.mCamera));
    }
```

But still having same problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many phones have maximum OpenGL ES texture size of 1024x1024, so you 1440 width might be the reason.

You can check your phones limit with an OpenGL query, see [How can I find the maximum texture size for different phones?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527695/how-an-i-find-the-maximum-texture-size-for-different-phones)

Answer (score 1):

Try `RatioResolutionPolicy` instead. [Problems when put large image in screen](http://www.andengine.org/forums/post19418.html#p19418)

AndEngine forums should always be your first place to search for answers

Comment: At first i tried with RatioResolutionPolicy only. But still having same problem

Answer (score -1):

You will have to use

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
```

In your image view tag,
it will automatically adjust to your screen,
if u are using it as a background image then you have to define in it your Linearlayout tag

Comment: But i am using andengine . I also implement this "fill_parent" in Manifest.xml file. But still same problem