# What is the meaning of class EGL14?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0

I'm working on Android with OpenGL. I grepped the code of `GLSurfaceView` and I noticed that it used the class `EGL10` to work with OpenGL.

Looking at the Javadoc of the Android platform, I noticed that there is another interesting class, `EGL14`, with almost the same methods and constants of `EGL10`.

So...what is the difference between `EGL10` and `EGL14`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are just different versions of EGL, which is the OpenGL window system interface used on Android.

- `EGL10` corresponds to EGL 1.0, which is the spec released in 2003.
- `EGL14` corresponds to [EGL 1.4](https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/), which is the spec released in 2014.

This means that `EGL14` is **much** more recent. The latest spec is EGL 1.5, released in 2015.

The unfortunate aspect is that the Android Java bindings for these two versions are quite different. While functionally EGL 1.4 is a superset of EGL 1.0 (at least AFAIK, I didn't compare the specs systematically), `EGL14` in Android is **not** an extended version of the `EGL10` API. So you can't just mix and match functionality between the two. You pretty much have to pick one, and stick with it.

Needless to say based on 11 years difference in release time, EGL 1.4 is greatly superior to EGL 1.0.

Now you might wonder why `GLSurfaceView` uses `EGL10` references in its interface. I don't know for sure, but I strongly suspect that it's for backwards compatibility. `EGL14` was only added in API level 17, while `GLSurfaceView` has been there since API level 3. To avoid breaking old apps, they would almost have to introduce a distinct version of `GLSurfaceView` that ties in with `EGL14`.

If you want to use `GLSurfaceView` and `EGL14` together, you have to jump through some hoops. For example, if you have a `EGLConfig` object from the `EGL10` interface, and want the corresponding `EGLConfig` object for use with the `EGL14` interface, the only way I found was to extract the config id from the original config, using the `EGL10` version of `eglGetConfigAttrib()`, and then query for the `EGL14` config using the `EGL14` version of `eglChooseConfig()`.

What adds to the "fun" when you start mixing the two versions is that they mostly use the same method names. This means that you have to use qualified names in source files where you deal with both versions.

Comment: Do you known about any book or tutorial about its use?

Comment: @xcesco I'm not familiar with any introductory material. The man pages are here: https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/sdk/docs/man/. They describe the C bindings, but the Java bindings are only a very thin layer on top of them. The spec document (which is fairly readable) is linked from https://www.khronos.org/registry/egl/. My answer here contains some typical code fragments: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26985858/gles10-glgetintegerv-returns-0-in-lollipop-only/27092070#27092070.