# How to render Bitmap off-screen in Android using OpenGL?

Tags: android, kotlin, bitmap, opengl-es

I need to render a bitmap without displaying it on the screen. For that I create OpenGL context using `EGL14` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27092070/502144). Then I save OpenGL surface to bitmap using `GLES20.glReadPixels`. But for some reason it is not rendered as expected and is just transparent.

```kotlin
import android.graphics.Bitmap
import android.opengl.*
import android.opengl.EGL14.EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION
import java.nio.ByteBuffer


class Renderer {

    private lateinit var display: EGLDisplay
    private lateinit var surface: EGLSurface
    private lateinit var eglContext: EGLContext

    fun draw() {
        // Just a stub that fills the bitmap with red color
        GLES20.glClearColor(1f, 0f, 0f, 1f)
        GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT)
    }

    fun saveBitmap(): Bitmap {
        val width = 320
        val height = 240
        val mPixelBuf = ByteBuffer.allocate(width * height * 4)
        GLES20.glReadPixels(0, 0, width, height, GLES20.GL_RGBA, GLES20.GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, mPixelBuf)
        return Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
    }

    private fun initializeEglContext() {
        display = EGL14.eglGetDisplay(EGL14.EGL_DEFAULT_DISPLAY)
        if (display == EGL14.EGL_NO_DISPLAY) {
            throw RuntimeException("eglGetDisplay failed ${EGL14.eglGetError()}")
        }

        val versions = IntArray(2)
        if (!EGL14.eglInitialize(display, versions, 0, versions, 1)) {
            throw RuntimeException("eglInitialize failed ${EGL14.eglGetError()}")
        }

        val configAttr = intArrayOf(
            EGL14.EGL_COLOR_BUFFER_TYPE, EGL14.EGL_RGB_BUFFER,
            EGL14.EGL_LEVEL, 0,
            EGL14.EGL_RENDERABLE_TYPE, EGL14.EGL_OPENGL_ES2_BIT,
            EGL14.EGL_SURFACE_TYPE, EGL14.EGL_PBUFFER_BIT,
            EGL14.EGL_NONE
        )
        val configs: Array<EGLConfig?> = arrayOfNulls(1)
        val numConfig = IntArray(1)
        EGL14.eglChooseConfig(
            display, configAttr, 0,
            configs, 0, 1, numConfig, 0
        )
        if (numConfig[0] == 0) {
            throw RuntimeException("No configs found")
        }
        val config: EGLConfig? = configs[0]

        val surfAttr = intArrayOf(
            EGL14.EGL_WIDTH, 320,
            EGL14.EGL_HEIGHT, 240,
            EGL14.EGL_NONE
        )
        surface = EGL14.eglCreatePbufferSurface(display, config, surfAttr, 0)

        val contextAttrib = intArrayOf(
            EGL_CONTEXT_CLIENT_VERSION, 2,
            EGL14.EGL_NONE
        )
        eglContext = EGL14.eglCreateContext(display, config, EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT, contextAttrib, 0)

        EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(display, surface, surface, eglContext)
    }

    fun destroy() {
        EGL14.eglMakeCurrent(display, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE, EGL14.EGL_NO_SURFACE,
            EGL14.EGL_NO_CONTEXT)
        EGL14.eglDestroySurface(display, surface)
        EGL14.eglDestroyContext(display, eglContext)
        EGL14.eglTerminate(display)
    }
}
```

This is how I use it:

```kotlin
val renderer = Renderer()
renderer.initializeEglContext()
renderer.draw()
val bitmap = renderer.saveBitmap()
renderer.destroy()
```

The code runs without any errors. I checked that context is created successfully. For example `GLES20.glCreateProgram` works as expected and returns a valid id. The only warning I get is

```
W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
```

But I'm not sure if it affects the result in any way.
However `bitmap` is not filled with color and is transparent:

```kotlin
val color = bitmap[0, 0]
Log.d("Main", "onCreate: ${Color.valueOf(color)}")
```

```
Color(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, sRGB IEC61966-2.1)
```

I guess that I'm missing something, but I can't figure out what. How to make it to actually render?

Comment: You forgot to call `glClear()` in your draw function. You’ve only set the color it uses to clear.

Comment: Thank you! That's not the first time I forget to call `glClear`. I fixed it in the question, as it is not the only reason, why the bitmap is not rendered, unfortunately.

Comment: Why your egl surface has dimensions 64x64? It should be 320x240.

Comment: @Hihikomori Fixed it, but the issue remains the same. In any case, bitmap should have pixels that are within the bounds, while the other pixels being undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pixel buffer must be copied to bitmap:

```
val mPixelBuf bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888)
bitmap.copyPixelsFromBuffer(mPixelBuf)
return bitmap
```