# Getting error "MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from Caches::initConstraints()" while working with mediaPlayer

Tags: android-mediaplayer

> 06-19 07:28:51.144    2744-2744/com.musicplayer E/OpenGLRenderer﹕
>   Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE from GradienCache 06-19 07:28:51.148
>   2744-2744/com.musicplayer E/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Getting MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE
>   from Caches::initConstraints()

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might be trying to load a graphic that is too large for the media player?  MAX_TEXTURE_SIZE can be checked via your code.  I suggest you check the value before using it if that makes sense in your application. 
see this answer for more info on how to check it- 
[stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4527695/how-an-i-find-the-maximum-texture-size-for-different-phones/4528043#4528043)