# How to make a line of it height more than 4096 pixel by android?

Tags: android, canvas, line, surfaceview

Here's the link to my other question: [SurfaceView setMeasuredDimension() with height greater than 4096 crashes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31020482/surfaceview-setmeasureddimension-with-height-greater-than-4096-crashes) It shows my question but so far I didn't find a way to solve it.
In fact,I just want to make a vertical curve line on the phone screen but its height should not be limited to less than 4096 pixels! I previously  designed it with 'SurfaceView',so the issue occurs as shown in that link.
Is there another way to achieve it?

Answer (score 0):

If your curve can be drawn procedurally on the fly, I would do that. Preparing such a large image may lead to performance issues.

If you really want to create image larger than your GPU texture limit, you can turn off hardware acceleration for that drawing.

Comment: My curve line needs random create and it's wobble,so i can't using image.now i will try to replace surfaceview of view.